# RealmSwift not saving properties

Tags: swift, realm

I have a simple User Object with a primary Key

```
class User: Object {
@objc dynamic var userId: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var name: String = ""
@objc dynamic var email: String = ""
@objc dynamic var gender: String = ""
@objc dynamic var heightCm: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var heightFeet: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var heightInches: Int = 0
@objc dynamic var weightUnits: String = ""
@objc dynamic var heightUnits: String = ""

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "userId"
    } 
}
```

User is Instantiated in viewdidLoad

```
    var user = User()
```

I save the entire object to Realm in its initial state so it's managed by Realm

But  when I want to write an individual property like this to Realm - it does NOT save.

```
let realm = try! Realm()

  try! realm.write {
        user.heightCm = 175
    }
}
```

When I read back the property user.heightCm it is still 0

If I save the entire object like this it works fine!

```
let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write {
  realm.add(user, update: .modified)
}
```

I don't want to save the entire object when only an individual property changes!
And according to the Realm latest documentation, it SHOULD work

[Realm documentation - Writes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Gyq.png)

But I can't get it to work.. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you're implementing realm quite right which is leading to the issue. This line is suspect `user.heightCm = 175` because we don't know where `user` came from. Either way, the code in that part of the question works correctly, but because it's incomplete snippets it's hard to know what the actual issue is. In general, it's a good idea to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can accurately assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this answer for clarity and to demonstrate realm functionality.

Given a person object with a primary key

```
class PersonClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var _id = 0
    @objc dynamic var name = "Jay"

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
    }
}
```

When the object is instantiated, it will default to a primary key of 0, and the name property will be Jay

```
let person = PersonClass()

let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(person)
}
```

[image]

As long as that object has not gone out of scope, the name can be changed. So let's instantiate the same object but change the name after

```
let person = PersonClass()

let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(person)  //creates the Jay object
}

try! realm.write {
    person.name = "Cindy" // name of that managed object is now Cindy
}
```

[image]

You can even read the object from realm, and update it later. Suppose in one part of your code the Jay PersonClass was written but then at a later time you wanted to update the name to Leroy

```
let realm = try! Realm()

if let jayObject = realm.objects(PersonClass.self).filter("name == 'Jay'").first {
    try! realm.write {
        jayObject.name = "Leroy"
    }
}
```

The end result of running that code is the PersonClass object that initially had a name of Jay being updated to a new name of Leroy

A final note that Integer primary keys can be troublesome. I would suggest using the ObjectId() class to generate unique primary keys. Please see the [Realm Documentation on Primary Keys](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/objects#primary-key) for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found the reason and although it IS in the documentation - it's a little misleading.

For anyone else having this problem.
It is to do with whether you have declared a primaryKey on your object!

Because my object has a primary key, the individual property update won't work UNLESS you specify the primary key associated with the object you are trying to update! This example where my primaryKey is 1 updates OK

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.create(user.self, value: ["userId": 1, "heightCm": 175 ], update: .modified)
    // Note* other properties of the user object will remain unchanged
}
```

Interestingly, Realm doesn't throw any errors at all if you attempt to update a property without specifying the primaryKey.. it just doesn't update the property!

Comment: No. This is not a correct answer and not a correct assumption. A realm object is a realm object regardless of whether is has a primary key or not. If you have a managed object you can freely modify and store any other those objects properties regardless of a primary key. The code in the initial part of your question works correctly - you really don't need anything like the code in this answer to update existing properties on a realm object - given that you are reading the object in correct to start with so it can be modified.

Comment: @Jay Hi, Thanks for the heads up - I am new to Swift - I had been using Realm in objc before now with no issues. The problem I have now, is that it will write the data to the Realm disk once.. Then running the same code again (with different values) - the data does NOT change. I have accidentally created a WORM :)

Comment: See my answer for known, good working examples and compare it to your code to see where the difference it.

Comment: Hi @Jay. Thanks for your help. The problem was that it WAS saving to the Realm Db, but when I closed and re-opened the app, I was overwriting it  with a partial user Object. 
I have taken your advice and used the ObjectId as primary key.
Thanks again.